# SharePoint JS Link file reference globally

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to ask that I have one document library with more than 20 views. I have implemented one JS link file to render required changes in the view.

My query is that is there any way to declare this JS link file globally for all the Document library views instead of adding reference in each view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: better to add manually in page.there is still hack  you can try add in master page but there is huge impact  it will display all your document library same, or try to put some condition in js link like url is "document library" and add in master page . be sure condition is proper otherwise it will impact whole site.

Comment: Thanks Jaynesh Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Update JS Link of list views Using PowerShell. Put all view links into an array and then iterating the links.

Sample script:

```
$webpartPages = "/Lists/Tickets/AllItems.aspx","/document%20li/Forms/1.aspx","/document%20li/Forms/2.aspx","/document%20li/Forms/AllItems.aspx";
$web = Get-SPWeb  http://url;
foreach($webpartPage in $webpartPages ){
$file = $web.GetFile($webPartPage)
$file.CheckOut()
$webPartManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($webPartPage, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared) 
$webpart = $webPartManager.WebParts[0]
$webpart.JSLink = "~sitecollection/SiteAssets/test12.js"#If you have placed your JS inside SiteAssets library of some CHILD site, you should use ~site/SiteAssets/... url.If you have placed your JS inside SiteAssets library of root site of site collection, you should use ~sitecollection/SiteAssets/... url.
$webPartManager.SaveChanges($webpart)
$file.CheckIn("Awesomeness has been delivered")
}
```

Or you could upload the js file to the SharePoint library, then modify the master page in sharepoint designer, add `<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://url/SiteAssets/test12.js"> </script>` to import the js file ,
You need to pay attention to determine whether current view is target view based on the URL in the js file, otherwise it may affect other pages.

Sample script :

```
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('document%20li') > 0) {
                SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
                    OnPostRender: function (ctx) {
                        var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
                        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                            var isApproved = rows[i]["testColumn"] == "Arvind Kushwaha1575353984864";
                            if (isApproved) {
                                var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                                var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
                                tr.style.backgroundColor = "#ada";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: Thanks Lee. Actually adding script in each view is already my consideration. However, I dont have permissions to touch the master page. I believe in SharePoint List template instance we have one Jslink reference, I think if somehow we change that that might fulfill our purpose. Anyhow, I will further investigate and implement it accordingly.  Thanks